# Previewing LaTeX fragments in org-mode not working

Tags: emacs, org-mode, dvipng

I've been trying to find a fix for this for a few days now and it's driving me crazy, so any help would be amazing. I'm trying to set my emacs up for making maths notes using org-mode. However, I've run into several problems displaying equations within org-mode.

First, when I used `c-c c-x c-l` I got the error,

```
can't find 'latex' (you need to install programs: latex and dvipng.)
```

I managed to find a fix for this using the following code in my init file:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat ":/Library/TeX/texbin/" (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin/")
```

but I now get a new error:

```
File "var/folders/z5/kbjq2cd50mv3fmzpwsr1s94h0000gn/T/orgtex905eux.dvi" wasn't produced. Please adjust 'dvipng' of 'org-preview-latex-process-alist'.
```

I've navigated to this file and found `orgtex905eux.tex` and manually converted this to a PNG using latex and dvipng in the terminal. As per [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/cant-preview-latex-fragment-in-emacs). And I noticed it adds a 1 to the end of the file name, but doesn't fix my problem.

Also I'm using mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

The same happen to me, and it turned out to be an error in the formula.

For example:

```
Incorrect formula:
\begin{equation}
   y[x/e'] =
   \begin{cases}
   e' & \text{if x = y}\\
   y  & \text{if x \neq y}
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}

Correct formula:
\begin{equation}
   y[x/e'] =
   \begin{cases}
   e' & \text{if x = y}\\
   y  & \text{if x $\neq$ y}
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
```

Notice the `$\neq$` (correct) vs `\neq` (incorrect).

I recommend that you debug your formula bit by bit.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Actually, the entire math expression within `\text` should be marked as math: `$x = y$` and `$x \neq y$`.  However, this doesn't really appear to answer the question.  (But I can't answer it either.)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `wasn't produced. Please adjust 'dvipng' of 'org-preview-latex-process-alist'` error: if on Linux, you might be missing some packages. This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

Couldn't tell which of the many latex packages was the one I was missing, despite having `latex` and `dvipng` available. The [Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html) (v9.5 retrieved 2022/08/20) says that those should be enough, though.

[Credits](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5rf9d4/comment/ddwfh9o/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)